# $\mathbb{R}^n\cong\mathbb{R}^m\Rightarrow n=m$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

There is the statement $$\mathbb{R}^n\cong\mathbb{R}^m\Rightarrow n=m.$$

I want to prove this using excision in algebraic topology.

In order to do so I have to find sets for which I can apply excision. here is my problem; I can't find them.

Comment: Deleting a point from each space leads to proving the corresponding statement for $S^n$ and $S^m$, which follows from homotopy, homology, etc.

Comment: This isn't much to go on. How would you plan to use excision? Excision could be part of the proof, but it would not be enough all on its own, and the application of excision is more likely to be buried somewhere in the proof of the homology calculations that you will need for proving this statement.

Comment: Depends on the meaning of $\simeq$.. if it means homeomorphism, then this is in Hatcher, Thm 2.26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the homology groups of spheres: Let $D^n$ be the unit disk in $R^n$. Then

$$H_i(R^n,R^n - 0) \cong H_i(D^n,D^n - 0) \cong \tilde{H}_{i-1}(D^n - 0) \cong \tilde{H}_{i-1}(S^{n-1})$$

and this yields distinct groups for all $n$.

Comment: I don'rt really recognize excision. For me it was like $H_n(X\setminus W, A\setminus W)\cong H_n (X,A)$ for $W\subset A\subset X$.

Comment: @R.A. Yes, and here $X = R^n, A = R^n - 0, W = R^n - D^n$. This yields the first isomorphism above.

Comment: Super and how du you get the second iso?

Comment: @R.A. from the long exact sequence of the pair

Comment: but what is $H^{\~}$?

Comment: @R.A. Assuming you mean $\tilde{H}$, it's reduced homology.